# How can I make a loop split 4 inputs between two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make a small behavior change to a block of code I inherited, the set up is unfortunately one very large function that is building out an html template and has a large number of for loops with in it.

Currently there is a section in the template function where a loop generates 4 text inputs with in a containing `<div>` along with submit button. What I would like to do is make it to where if in the case that this specific area has more than two inputs then put two inside of one `<div>` with a subit and then the other two with in another div with its own submit, so essentially splitting them up. Here is a quick and (very) dirty visual example of what I am trying to achieve.

http://jsbin.com/izejin/5/

And below is the current loop that is generating the 4 inputs into the single `<div>`. My  thought is that I need to set up a counter that upon being === 2 will create the new html elements with new classes that will style them as need be. But I'm unsure how to achieve that while still keeping the loop going.

```
if (measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes.length > 1) {

    newNodeHtml += "<div id='" + measurementClass + "-3-" + measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes[0].TargetConfigure[0].TargetType + "' class='target-metric input " + measurementClass + "-input'>";

    for (var k = 0; k < measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes.length; k++) {
        var mType = measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes[k];
        var userTarget = mType.UserTarget;
        var targetConfigure = mType.TargetConfigure[0]; 

        newNodeHtml += "<div><span>" + mType.MeasurementTypeName + " TARGET</span>" +
                    "<input type='text' id='txt-" + measurementClass + "-3-" + mType.MeasurementTypeID + "' placeholder='" + mType.UnitName + "' value='" + targetHighValue + "' " + disableAttribute + "></div>";
    }

    newNodeHtml += "<a onclick='CellClicked(" + mTypeGroupID + ", 3, 3)'><span class='check-range'></span></a>" +
            "</div>";
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: unless they are in separate <form> tags both submits will do the same thing.

Comment: Well I would not mind keeping it to one submit button that appears only in the second div. The first div could contain a "next" button.

Comment: Quick? Set a second counter and restart it every time it reaches the value of 2.

Comment: This would essentially be the same thing as abc123's method below right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need, it is a nested `loop` with a `number of loops` and an `index`

```
if (measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes.length > 1) {
    var index = 0;
    var numberOfLoops = Math.ceil(measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes.length / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++) {
        var newNodeHtml = '';
        newNodeHtml += "<div id='" + measurementClass + "-3-" + measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes[0].TargetConfigure[0].TargetType + "' class='target-metric input " + measurementClass + "-input'>";

        for (index; index < index + 2; index++) {
            if(measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes[index] === undefined)
                break;

            var mType = measurementTypeGroup.MeasurementTypes[index];
            var userTarget = mType.UserTarget;
            var targetConfigure = mType.TargetConfigure[0];

            newNodeHtml += "<div><span>" + mType.MeasurementTypeName + " TARGET</span>" +
                "<input type='text' id='txt-" + measurementClass + "-3-" + mType.MeasurementTypeID + "' placeholder='" + mType.UnitName + "' value='" + targetHighValue + "' " + disableAttribute + "></div>";
        }

        newNodeHtml += "<a onclick='CellClicked(" + mTypeGroupID + ", 3, 3)'><span class='check-range'></span></a>" +
            "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm using this method, only one of the inputs displays and it's not creating the next stage of inputs.

Comment: Aha! so that is now looping the containers, thanks. I can give the second div a different class to handle style (most likely use the index) just wire up a next button. But all four inputs are still on the first div rather than 2 on one and 2 on the other. Which seems like it shouldn't be happening now.

Comment: @Stavros_S yeah according to the above code it shouldn't be doing what you are saying but interesting.

Comment: I set the first 'newNodeHtml' in the for loop to use MeasuremnetTypes[k] rather than zero. So that is giving me a proper increasing class name ( class="3-3" and class="3-4"). But still its as if the loop is breaking like it should for the divs now but not for the actual inputs.

Comment: i had a typo  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; k++) { should of been  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++) {, the variable k doesn't exist in my example so change your indexer to i if you are using my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33657/discussion-between-abc123-and-stavros-s)